# Creation of a NodeJS web app in Azure fails

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Using [this official Azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs), I was able to perform all the steps until the step `Browse to the app` where when I browse to the app using `http://myNodeJsTestApp.azurewebsites.net` I get the following error:

> > The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Please note that using same URL that tutorial asks us to use in step `Set Node.js runtime` of the tutorial, I was able to successfully display the exact same screen shown in that section. So the error is occurring after I got to the step `Browse to the app` further down. I'm using `NodeJS version 8.12.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow exactly the steps and don't modify the sample code, the only fault causing Internal server error is the node version 8.12.0.

Azure server doesn't install Node.js of all existing versions, go `https://yourwebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/diagnostics/runtime` to check available ones.

I recommend to use 8.11.1 LTS version as the tutorial suggests, or you can choose 10.6.0 the latest on Azure.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thank you for helping me. I followed the instructions in section `Set Node.js runtime` of the tutorial to set the version to `8.11.1` and the error was gone..